# cmake and building android for 64-bit project

Tags: android, cmake

We use Hunter for package management.  Our solution is a mix of native and java code.  To build the native code we use cmake.

Now we want to build our Android project with 64-bit support.  `Gradle` invokes `cmake` and passes

> build for system processor:              aarch64

Now, in our native side, there are sources for `arm64` but `cmake` looks for sources under `aarch64` folder.

Is there any way to inform `cmake` to treat `aarch64` same as `arm64`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating symlink to `arm64` and named it `aarch64`.